# SQL Server - I need to understand the logic of the query to remove characters from string

Tags: sql-server

I've found this query while trying to remove all the characters from a phone column, leaving only numbers. It works, but I can't understand the logic behind all the steps to replicate to other uses.

```
DECLARE @test TABLE(x VARCHAR(20));

INSERT INTO @test
SELECT '+91 (876) 098 6789' UNION ALL
SELECT '1-567-987-7655' UNION ALL
SELECT 'FR5-5105'

insert into @test values ('+91 (876) 098 6789');
insert into @test  values ('1-567-987-7655');
insert into @test  values ('FR5-5105')
insert into @test  values ('FR5@:!~~678-5105')


WITH Num1 (n) AS (
SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 ),
Num2 (n) AS (SELECT 1 FROM Num1 AS X, Num1 AS Y),
Num3 (n) AS (SELECT 1 FROM Num2 AS X, Num2 AS Y),
Num4 (n) AS (SELECT 1 FROM Num3 AS X, Num3 AS Y),
Nums (n) AS (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY n) FROM Num4),
Cleaner AS (
SELECT x, (SELECT CASE WHEN SUBSTRING(x, n, 1) NOT LIKE '[^0-9]'
                       THEN SUBSTRING(x, n, 1)
                      ELSE ''
                  END + ''
           FROM Nums
           WHERE n <= LEN(x)
           FOR XML PATH('')) AS x_clean
FROM @test )
SELECT x, x_clean
FROM Cleaner;
```

Comment: Scan the web for articles for "tally" or "table of numbers" articles, and you'll eventually run into lengthy and detailed discussions of that query.

Answer (score 1):

The num 1 to 4 part basically generates a list of numbers.

The join between the numbers and the length of the string '<=LEN(x)', makes that each character can be plotted on a separate row and accessed by index by means of the generated row_number().

Then any character that is not 0-9 is substituted by an empty string. The output FOR XML glues the string back together again while ignoring the empty strings.